# How to test an API with filters

Tags: api, rest, query-string

I've received a documentation from a developer for an API i have to test.
I have the API URL: https://something/get-list
As per the documentation, the accepted paremeters are:

- token (required)
- filters[is_true] – 0 or 1

I'm trying to figure it out how to input the filters[is_true] in query params in postman. No matter what i do the response is not filtered, and i want to test the api.
I've tried with key filters[is_true], $filter=filters[is_true] etc, but doesn't work.

I do not have much experience with APIs and I didn't test before with filters so not sure what to do.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: how about just `filters` ?

Comment: @KenChan you mean key= filters and value = 1? doesn't work anyway :(, tried key: filters / value: [is_true]=1 or just 1